# TCP/IP: set socket option for keep-alive after connection has been established

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, window, lwip

Is it possible to set a socket's `SO_KEEPALIVE` option (TCP keep alive interval and TCP keep alive value) after some hypothetical application level handshake? Or does it have to be set before a call to `accept`?

I'm concerned with interoperability between Linux, Windows and  the eCos lwIP stack, so information about both platforms is appreciated.

Comment: You can set it any time. Of course there is no socket to set it on prior  to the `accept(),` unless you can set it on the listening socket and let it be inherited by all accepted sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As EJP said, you can set it any time. The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) says:

> setsockopt()  manipulate  options  for  the  socket referred to by the file descriptor *sockfd*.

You can set or unset `SO_KEEPALIVE` like this

```
int iOption = 1; // Turn on keep-alive, 0 = disables, 1 = enables
if (setsockopt(socketHandle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (const char *) &iOption,  sizeof(int)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
           cerr << "Set keepalive: Keepalive option failed" << endl;
    }
```

You can also read this [tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Sockets.html) for more details.